# How do I connect a Mule application to Postman with OAuth2.0, I cant find the client secret or key

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform, appian

I want to establish an integration between Appian and mulesoft using OAuth2.0 authorization but I cant find the key or secret anywhere on Runtime Manager dashboard.

I know there's a prebuilt integration for Appian built by MuleSoft but for my requirement, I cant use that.

Comment: There is no MuleSoft workflow or dashboard. Please use correct terminology. Maybe you are talking about a Mule application (which has flows) and Runtime Manager dashboards?

Comment: Do you mean how to authenticate **from** Postman **to** a Mule application with OAuth 2.0?

Comment: Im using the Anypoint design center

Comment: What are you designing, and API or a flow?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single way to implement OAuth 2.0 in Mule applications so it will depend on your application and features from different MuleSoft products that you may be using. Runtime Manager is used only to manage deployment and execution of applications. That does not include OAuth nor API features. If you have [API Manager](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/getting-started-proxy) in your subscription you could use policies to apply an OAuth policy to a Mule application that implements an API.